# Office Addin command taskpane button icon is not shown

Tags: office-js

I'm developing Word Web Add-in and facing ribbon button icon issues; it's not showing up.

I've searched a lot and seen a few questions here but nevertheless, I've passed all suggestions from there and it still doesn't work.

I'm using Add-in Commands and I have only one ribbon button whose icon points to my server over `https`. I can grab image through any browser.

There are a couple of odd things:

- The icon is shown in Word Online and Word for Mac but *not* with Word for Windows.
- If I start server locally, it works.
- If I move icons another service such as `imugr.com`, it also works.
- The certificate on my server is valid there are no warnings/errors.
- All icons are `PNG` format

Here is my manifest:

```xml
<!-- from Group -->
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
    <Supertip>
        <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
        <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
        <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
        <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
    </Supertip>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="tpicon_16x16"/>
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="tpicon_32x32"/>
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="tpicon_80x80"/>
    </Icon>
    <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
        <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
        <!-- Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane. -->
        <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
    </Action>
</Control>

<!-- from Resources -->
<bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://validurl.com/wa/Images/R16X16.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://validurl.com/wa/Images/R32X32.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://validurl.com/wa/Images/R80X80.png"/>
</bt:Images>
```

HTTP trace when fetching the image:

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 22:51:38 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 16:24:36 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 835
Vary: User-Agent
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: Can you add the HTTP traffic for the failed scenario?

Comment: Thanks for a quick response) There jetty server on the other side you meant logs from it didn't you ? or try to wireshark while inserting addin?

Comment: I'm looking for the traffic on the client so either WireShark or Fiddler should do the trick.

Comment: Is it possible I'll send it to you in private the fiddler capture?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 22:51:38 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 16:24:36 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 835
Vary: User-Agent
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

It is the same answer for all icon requests

[link to pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8cEXN74P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by your `Cache-Control` header. Word for Windows caches the ribbon image for performance reasons. When you specify that it *cannot* cache these images then Word will simply fail to load them.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
```

You need to configure your web server such that images do not have a `Cache-Control` header added to them.

Comment: Thanks I've turned it off at all but it didn't help. What about Pragma header? might  it cause the issue?

Comment: I completely missed that one. I haven't seen  `Pragma` used in a long time, it only applies to `HTTP/1.0` clients (which one would hope are no longer being used anywhere). That should be removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marc LaFleur - MSFT  the issue is solved. In order to make it work I would not have turned off `Cache-Control` but set it to `public, max-age=<value you want>`. As to `Pragma` header it should be turned off totally. So now it works.
There is one more useful link [Office-Add-in-Commands-FAQ](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/FAQ.md) section **Debug: Icons not showing**